# Why isn't this valid housing?

Tags: terraria

[image: da house in question]

Material is wood, I confirmed I can set my spawn using a bed in it, and there's a chair and table along with light sources. I did this in the old patch of terraria as well and it worked fine, but now it doesn't?

Comment: It's either too small, or your wall is incomplete at the bottom.

Comment: No, I made sure the dimensions were correct, aswell as the wall complete. It still doesn't show up as valid housing.